# conditional criteria in access 2003

Tags: sql, ms-access-2003

I am fairly new to Access 2003, and I've been having some issues with what I think is called an inner join.  I have two tables that I have no ability to edit, so I am querying them and the information in one of the two tables relates to profiles of users and the second is auxilary information relating to them like email addresses.

My issue is that I need to apply criteria to table 2 (auxilary), but sometimes the record doesn't exist because not all of table 1 has a match in table 2.  So I have selected to preserve all fields from table 1 and only matching for table 2, but due to my criteria for table 2, I will never get a result unless there is values in table 2.

I have a field in table 1 that lets me know if there will be values in table 2, so what I want to do is some sort of 
`if table1val = "1" Then table2val Like "*01*"`.  So far this has not worked, likely due to error on my part, so I was wondering if this is possible in design view, because from looking it up it seems like it may be possible in sql view, but I've had no luck attempting this due to my lack of sql knowledge.

edit: what I had that was working
criteria for table2:

under note_txt: `Like "*help*" Or Like "*HELP*" Or Like "*Help*"`

under category_code: `"Emails" Or "Email"`

under high_priority_ind: `Like "-1"`

These all work, but will return nothing if the field shows #Deleted

the field in table1 I would like to have these criteria be based on is when
 prod_marker: `Not Like "0"`

My understanding is you cannot have an if in a criteria because say if you put "1" as the criteria for table 1 it acts like table1 = 1, and you cant have table1 = if.  So is there a better way of going about this, because it seems I cant have

```
If(Not (prod_marker) Like "0") Then ((high_priority_ind) Like "-1")
```

Below is the SQL that I've been able to come up with that just crashes my access (I didnt include the SELECT and FROM because its long and I wasnt sure if it was necessary):

```
WHERE (((dbo_client_link.link_id_txt)=[Enter Policy Number]) AND
 ((dbo_client_link.link_relationship_code)="O" Or 
(dbo_client_link.link_relationship_code)="J") AND 
((dbo_producer.aga_direct_ind)  Like "0") Or 
(((dbo_producer.aga_direct_ind) Like "-1" ) And 
( (dbo_note.note_txt) Like "*help*" Or 
(dbo_note.note_txt) Like "*HELP*") AND 
((dbo_note.category_code)="Emails" Or 
(dbo_note.category_code)="Email") AND 
((dbo_note.high_priority_ind) Like -1)))
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry, is that better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My issue is that I need to apply criteria to table 2 (auxilary), but sometimes the record doesn't exist because not all of table 1 has a match in table 2.

You need to use a left join from `Table1` (main) to `Table2` (auxillary). If you're doing this in Design View, you should be able to right-click the join (line between the 2 tables), then go to Join Properties. You want to select **Include all records from Table1 and only those records from Table2 where the joined fields are equal**

Now you can use the `Table1.prod_marker <> "0"` expression as a criterion (you don't need the LIKE operator, since you're not using a wildcard search). Going along these lines: What types of values are in the `prod_marker` field? Is it only "0" and "1", or do you have other possible values? If you're only ever going to see either "0" or "1", you can also use `Table1.prod_marker = 1`

If you also want to filter records based on values in `Table2`, you can add OR criteria (like `high_priority_ind = "-1"`, `UCASE(note_txt) like "*HELP*"`, and `UCASE(category_code) like "*EMAIL*"`

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I'm pretty sure your answer is the solution, but due to the sheer volume of the records I'm sorting through my access keeps crashing.  I think I will just have to leave out the criteria in table2, and parse throught the data using vba instead.

Comment: That's unfortunate. And you don't have the ability to change the table structure, right? If you did, you could make a number of improvements that would help your querying (change the `prod_marker` and `high_priority` fields to integers or Yes/No, and create a separate table to store categories).

Comment: Unfortunately no, what I just tried and worked though for anyone with a similar issue is to just have two queries, one with the criteria and one without, and on form open with the no criteria query as the record source, checking for the marker, and switching the recordsource to the other query if the marker indicates its populated.  Its not pretty, but it works for now.